# Postfix evaluation 3

Tags: java

i have worked for this question couple of days and im at the end. Code works well for the input numbers between 0 and 9. but when input is more than 9 for example 28 72 * 13 + 20 67 *  + it doesn't print correct answer. I don't know what to implement in order to code work.
I cant change main function. I can change only inside of static int evaluatePostfix(char [] izraz, int n)

Note: I fixed it.

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

interface Stack<E> {

    // The elements of the Stack are any kind of objects

    // Access methods:

    public boolean isEmpty ();
        // Returns true only if the stack is empty.

 public E peek ();

    public void clear ();
        // Clears the stack.

    public void push (E x);
        // Adds x on the top of the stack.

    public E pop ();
        // Removes and returns the element on the top.


}

class ArrayStack<E> implements Stack<E> {
    private E[] elems;
    private int depth;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ArrayStack (int maxDepth) {
        // Creating new empty stack
        elems = (E[]) new Object[maxDepth];
        depth = 0;
    }


    public boolean isEmpty () {
         // Returns true only if the stack is empty.

        return (depth == 0);
    }

  public E peek () {
        // Returns the element on the top od the stack.
        if (depth == 0)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        return elems[depth-1];
    }


    public void clear () {
        // Clears the stack.
        for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++)  elems[i] = null;
        depth = 0;
    }


    public void push (E x) {
        // Adds x on the top of the stack.
        elems[depth++] = x;
    }


    public E pop () 
    {
        // Removes and returns the element on the top.
        if (depth == 0)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        E topmost = elems[--depth];
        elems[depth] = null;
        return topmost;
    }


}


public class PostFixEvaluation 
{    
    static int evaluate(int op1, int op2, char ch)
    {
        switch (ch) {
      case '*': return op2 * op1;
      case '/': return op2 / op1;
      case '+': return op2 + op1;
      case '-': return op2 - op1;
      default : return 0;
   }
}


    static int evaluatePostfix(char [] izraz, int n)
{
        ArrayStack<String> e = new ArrayStack<String>(n);
        char ch=0;
        int op1,op2,result=0;
        int i=0;
      while(i<n)
    {
            if(izraz[i]=='+' || izraz[i]=='-' || izraz[i]=='/' || izraz[i]=='*')
           {
                ch=izraz[i];
                op1 =Integer.parseInt(e.pop());
                op2 =Integer.parseInt(e.pop());
                result=evaluate(op1,op2,ch);    
                e.push(Integer.toString(result));                 
           }

          else
       {
         final StringBuilder number= new StringBuilder();
if(Character.isDigit(izraz[i]))
            {
         while (izraz[i] != ' ') 
          {
           number.append(izraz[i]);
           i++;    
          }

         e.push(number.toString());
         continue;
            }
       } 
            i++;                          
    }


        return result;
}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        String expression = br.readLine();
        char exp[] = expression.toCharArray();

        int rez = evaluatePostfix(exp, exp.length);
       System.out.println(rez);

        br.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: whats this statement doing Character.isDigit(izraz[i+1]){}?

Comment: sorry i was trying something its not in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Character, try String like below:

Replace this code:

```
    ArrayStack<Character> e = new ArrayStack(n);
    char ch=0,res=0,a,b;
    int op1,op2,result=0,c=0;
    int z;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
       if(Character.isDigit(izraz[i]))
       {

          ch=izraz[i];

          e.push(ch);  


       }
        if(izraz[i]=='+' || izraz[i]=='-' || izraz[i]=='/' || izraz[i]=='*')
       {
           ch=izraz[i];

           op1 =e.pop()-'0';
            //System.out.print(op1+" ");

           op2 =e.pop()-'0';
```

With:

```
    ArrayStack<String> e = new ArrayStack<String>(n);
    char ch=0;
    int op1,op2,result=0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
       if(Character.isDigit(izraz[i]))
       {
         final StringBuilder number= new StringBuilder();

         while (izraz[i] != ' ') {
           number.append(izraz[i]);
           i++;    
         }

         e.push(number.toString());

          continue;
       }
        if(izraz[i]=='+' || izraz[i]=='-' || izraz[i]=='/' || izraz[i]=='*')
       {
           ch=izraz[i];

           op1 =Integer.parseInt(e.pop());
            //System.out.print(op1+" ");

           op2 =Integer.parseInt(e.pop());
```

Comment: it gives this error : PostFixEvaluation.java:111: error: method push in class ArrayStack cannot be applied to given types;
         e.push(number.toString());
          ^
  required: Character
  found: String
  reason: actual argument String cannot be converted to Character by method invocation conversion

Comment: Thank you very much man i forgot ArrayStack<String> e = new ArrayStack<String>(n); now i fixed and it worked.